# Array --- list showing all 0s. How to fix

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to code an array that displays up to 20 numbers that have been entered into the calculator. For some reason, my code is displaying zero 20 times. I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong and I feel like it's something obvious. Can someone please help? I really don't want to cheat, I just want to be pointed in the right direction.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int Count = 0;
    decimal Total = 0m;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Score = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);

        Total += Score;
        Count++;

        decimal Average = Total / Count;

        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
        txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();
        txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();




    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Count = 0;
        decimal Total = 0m;
        decimal Average = 0m;
        decimal Score = 0m;

        txtScore.Text = Score.ToString();
        txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();
        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
        txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();





        txtScore.Focus();

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        decimal[] scores = new decimal[20];

        MessageBox.Show("The scores entered are " + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[0] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[1] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[2] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[3] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[4] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[5] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[6] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[7] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[8] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[9] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[10] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[11] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[12] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[13] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[14] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[15] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[16] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[17] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[18] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[19] + Environment.NewLine, "Scores List");



    }
}
```

}

Comment: tip: you should use string.join(delimiter,yourArray) to display an array or list without having to type all the elements or loop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new array of empty decimals whenever btnDisplay is clicked. This is why it always displays 20 0's.

You'd need to change the scope of the array so that it can be accessed throughout all of your class. That means that you would then use that variable in the `btnDisplay_click`. The required number needs to be inserted into the array on `btnAdd_Click`.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int Count = 0;
    decimal Total = 0m;
    decimal[] scores = new decimal[20];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Score = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);

        //Add the score to the array
        scores[Count] = Score;

        Total += Score;
        Count++;

        decimal Average = Total / Count;

        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
        txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();
        txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Count = 0;
        decimal Total = 0m;
        decimal Average = 0m;
        decimal Score = 0m;

        txtScore.Text = Score.ToString();
        txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();
        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
        txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();


        txtScore.Focus();

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("The scores entered are " + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[0] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[1] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[2] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[3] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[4] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[5] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[6] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[7] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[8] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[9] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[10] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[11] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[12] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[13] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[14] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[15] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[16] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[17] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[18] + Environment.NewLine +
            scores[19] + Environment.NewLine, "Scores List");

    }

}
```

The array would also need to be cleared on `btnClear_Click`.

Comment: Cool. Just want to notice, that `scores` in this case is a field. It is not a *global variable*, which is a completely different concept, not even directly supported in С#.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser You're 100% right, that's my own bad habit coming through.

Comment: To reduce the line of code, you can try this way to prepare the message                                   

          
 string  finalStr = "The scores entered are " + Environment.NewLine;

            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                finalStr += scores[i] + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(finalStr, "Scores List");

Comment: Yeah, there's a few improvements that I didn't add in & have left to OP. There's also the issue of what to do if more than 20 numbers are added.

Answer (score 0):

In `btnDisplay_Click` you create `scores` array but you do not put anything in it. then you display its content. It shows 20 zeroes as expected.

You have to make `scores` a field if you want to fill it in `btnAdd_Click`.